# Proper way to install bash 4.2 on OS X 10.9 Mavericks from source, without getting "abort trap: 6" and segfaults

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

I tried to install bash 4.2 from source (not homebrew). It sort of runs, sort of fails. When I make it my default login shell, I can run many commands, but often basic commands such as cd /System kill the shell.

I downloaded the master updated tarball, and I basically installed it with the equivalent of this:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash4
sudo bash -c "echo /bin/bash4 >> /private/etc/shells"
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash # A
```

...and I also went to System Prefs -> Users and Groups -> (me) -> Advanced Options and changed the default shell to /bin/bash4.

Homebrew seems to install readline and require that, as well as add an additional flag for -DSSH_SOURCE_BASHRC to the environment (which shouldn't be a problem for what I'm doing)

Comment: What do you mean by "kill the shell?" Are there any error messages or does the shell just close out completely?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: From bash 3 shell, when I run the bash 4.2 shell via /bin/bash4, then run cd /System, I get "Abort trap: 6" as the error, and it drops back to the bash 3 shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

workaround: change \w to \W in PS1.

Comment: In my ~/.bashrc that worked. \W and \w have different functions, do you by chance know why \W doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @Brian, if you provide a core dump for your particular case, i might be able to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

the problem seems to be this line when t_string does not start with $HOME.
(parse.y:5278)

```
  strcpy (t_string, polite_directory_format (t_string));
```

a quick and dirty fix:

```
diff --git i/general.c w/general.c
index 491a7ea267ab..ec9b6271015d 100644
--- i/general.c
+++ w/general.c
@@ -700,10 +700,11 @@ polite_directory_format (name)
       strncpy (tdir + 1, name + l, sizeof(tdir) - 2);
       tdir[0] = '~';
       tdir[sizeof(tdir) - 1] = '\0';
-      return (tdir);
     }
   else
-    return (name);
+    strcpy (tdir, name);
+
+  return (tdir);
 }

 /* Trim NAME.  If NAME begins with `~/', skip over tilde prefix.  Trim to
```

it boils down to this test case that compiles and runs with gcc but fails with clang/llvm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *foo(char *buf) {
  return(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buf[1024];

  strcpy(buf, "buffer");

  strcpy(buf, foo(buf));
  printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

.

```
> gcc -o test test.c
> ./test
buffer
> cc -o test test.c
> ./test
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: There's an open issue on Homebrew on this exact problem and they reached the same conclusion: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23470